# how to know the value of clicked checkbox in bootstarp multi select checkbox dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, bootstrap-multiselect

I am using bootstarp multi select checkbox dropdown for selecting multiple values. On checking or unchecking a value in drop-down I am getting the list of values which are selected, but how can I get the clicked value.

**For example:** I have a multi select checkbox drop-down with values apple, ball, cat. And apple and cat are selected on page load. If I uncheck apple how can I get the value **apple**.

Comment: Take a look at the [onChange](http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/#configuration-options-onChange) event.

Answer (score 1):

You should check the `onChange` event like this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#example').multiselect({
            onChange: function(option, checked, select) {
                alert('Changed option ' + $(option).val() + '.');
            }
        });
    });
```

Here is the working example: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hubswk10/1/).